# Concept Clarification: Sum of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$. Then the sum $U+W$ is the subspace:

$U+W = \{u+w: u \in U, w \in W\}$

I'm having trouble understand what this means. So if I have the following subspaces $U$ and $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ say:

$U = \{\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}: x+y+z=0\}$

$W = \{\begin{pmatrix}
-5x\\ 
3x\\
4x
\end{pmatrix}:$ $x$ is an arbitrary number$\}$

So, if I list some elements of each subspace,

$U = \{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
-2
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
3\\
-5
\end{pmatrix},...\}
$

$W = \{\begin{pmatrix}
-5\\
3\\
4
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
-10\\
6\\
8
\end{pmatrix},...\}
$

Does this mean $U+W = \{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
-2
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
-5\\
3\\
4
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
-2
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
-10\\
6\\
8
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
3\\
-5
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
-5\\
3\\
4
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
3\\
-5
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
-10\\
6\\
8
\end{pmatrix}, ....
\}
$

Comment: Yes, that's  what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're writing is exactly correct, although I can see why it would be a bit confusing from this perspective.  It can be tedious to list out infinitely many elements...

A better way to view the space $U+W$ is to write it in formal set notation to get a sense of what an arbitrary vector looks like.

$$U+W=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a-5d\\b+3d\\c+4d\end{pmatrix}\middle|a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R},\;a+b+c=0\right\}$$

So now we can see the form that all vectors have in $U+W$.  Now, can you show that any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has this form, so that in fact $U+W=\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Jared thanks! Do we consider the matrix with columns $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), (-5,3,4)$ | $(b1,b2,b3)$, where $(b1,b2,b3) \in R^3$ and you can see that there are infinitely many solutions, so every vector in $R^3$ can be written in that form?